# Limiting how many checkboxes can be checked on Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to limit how many checkboxes can be checked on my gravity forms. But it makes an error. This is my code :

```
new GFLimitCheckboxes(2, array(37 => array('max' => 2)));
```

My error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'GFLimitCheckboxes' not found in /Prohai/wp-content/themes/prohai/functions.php on line 272
```

Comment: You need to include the GFLimitCheckboxes class. Have you included it in your website?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. Appreciate your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

msbodetti is correct. You need to include the GFLimitCheckboxes class either in your theme's functions.php file or via a snippet manager plugin ([like this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)). Refer to the full article for details:

http://gravitywiz.com/limiting-how-many-checkboxes-can-be-checked/

If you don't want to be bothered with the code, this functionality is available as a plugin with [Gravity Perks](http://gravityperks.com) and can be administered from the field settings for your checkbox fields. The "perk" you're interested in is called "GP Limit Checkboxes". Here is a link to the documentation for the plugin-version which includes some examples of what it looks like in action.

http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-limit-checkboxes/